# Bulk shift subset dataframe columns at certain rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Feels like this should not be complicated but I'm at a mental block right now. Where ColA = 'dog', I want to shift columns 'ColC' and 'ColD' by 100. I know I can do this with .loc for example: df_original.loc[(df_original.ColA =='dog'), 'ColC'] = df_original.ColC +100......HOWEVER -  I have a lot of columns I need to bulk shift like this and this seems excessive. My dataframe also has other columns that DO NOT need shifted. Any ideas of shortcuts?

Original DF

```
ColA      ColB     ColC      ColD
cat        60       80        10
cat        32       10        40
cat        0        200       64
dog        23       2         55
dog        43       1000      12
dog        1        80        44
dog        500      50        90
bird       8        12        25
```

Desired DF

```
ColA      ColB     ColC      ColD
cat        60       80        10
cat        32       10        40
cat        0        200       64
dog        23       102       155
dog        43       1100      112
dog        1        180       144
dog        500      150       190
bird       8        12        25
```

Comment: Could you give an indication of how you would select the columns? do they have a common name, or do they start from a particular position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us do

```
df.loc[df.ColA.isin(['dog']),['ColC','ColD']] +=100

df
Out[461]: 
   ColA  ColB  ColC  ColD
0   cat    60    80    10
1   cat    32    10    40
2   cat     0   200    64
3   dog    23   102   155
4   dog    43  1100   112
5   dog     1   180   144
6   dog   500   150   190
7  bird     8    12    25
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a mask:

```
new_values = df.filter(['ColC', 'ColD']).mask(df.ColA.eq('dog'),
                                             lambda df: df+100)

df.assign(**new_values)

   ColA  ColB  ColC  ColD
0   cat    60    80    10
1   cat    32    10    40
2   cat     0   200    64
3   dog    23   102   155
4   dog    43  1100   112
5   dog     1   180   144
6   dog   500   150   190
7  bird     8    12    25
```